# Как создать бесконечную анимацию вверх и вниз?

Tags: css, css3

Смог добиться бесконечности, только постоянно перемещая ползунок, а мне надо что бы сначала до конца, а потом с конца на начало:

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #333;
}

.header-down {
  width: 1px;
  height: 65px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  z-index: 92;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-down::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #3cc9e5;
  transform: translate3d(0, - 100%, 0);
  animation: spin .7s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-down">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #333;
}

.header-down {
  width: 1px;
  height: 65px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  z-index: 92;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-down::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #3cc9e5;
  transform: translate3d(0, - 100%, 0);
  animation: spin 1.4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-down">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте. Вот самый простой способ решения:

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #333;
}

.header-down {
  width: 1px;
  height: 65px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  z-index: 92;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-down::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #3cc9e5;
  transform: translate3d(0, - 100%, 0);
  animation: spin .7s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0,100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-down">
</div>
```